# Facebook Canvas app on Google App engine - Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options in Google Chrome

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, x-frame-options

I am trying to build an app with backend on Google App engine. It works fine on Firefox 3.6, Firefox 6, IE 9. But on Google Chrome 17.0.963.83m, it's failing with "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.". I tried opening my app on another computer on Google Chrome (same version), although it throws the same error, but the app starts successfully. Tried clearing cache etc.

My header in developer tools likes this -

```
cache-control:private
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:966
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Sun, 25 Mar 2012 19:12:16 GMT
server:Google Frontend
status:200 OK
vary:Cookie, Accept-Encoding
version:HTTP/1.1
```

There is no x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN or DENY. Can't figure out why it fails. Any solutions?

I have tried the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767901/1291712. It supposedly requires setting 2 values for same the header options. Specifically --

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-frame-optoins: GOFORIT
```

I am using [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) as the web framework. I don't know how can you set two values for the same header in django. I tried setting it to "GOFORIT" and "SAMEORIGIN, GOFORIT", but no success.

What else can I try to debug and solve? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had [Facebook Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejpepffjfmamnambagiibghpglaidiec) installed on my chrome and so it wouldn't load.
Wasted an entire evening. Argh!

Comment: hi there, any other ideas, i get the error without that facebook diconnect thing....

Comment: @CoffeJunky: Check the request first in firebug/chrome developer tools. See if x-frame-options is really set in the response header. Also note that Google Chrome gives this error on Facebook Apps due to some reason, although it'll display the app. Basically test your requests and make sure they are doing what they should do. If you don't have x-frame-options in the response header and you still don't see the app, you're doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Ty for the reply, I redesigned my app, so it was possible to launche the all without errors.